# ThisWorkbook generates Runtime Error 9: Subscript Out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

The basic idea of this (from the array names) are timesheets.

I have a Master Time sheet that has everyones' name on it, + the days.

The Concept is, open the http link from L/UBounds of array. Grab the data from the specific sheet, put it in my master sheet, close out that workbook, move on to next name.

```
Sub PassToProc()
Dim arr(4) As String
arr(0) = "https://sharepoint/Time Sheets/Jeff.xlsm"
arr(1) = "https://sharepoint/Time Sheets/Jonathan.xlsm"
arr(2) = "https://sharepoint/Time Sheets/Jim.xlsm"
arr(3) = "https://sharepoint/Time Sheets/Topher.xlsm"
arr(4) = "https://sharepoint/Time Sheets/Brandon.xlsm"
' Pass the array to function
UseArray arr
End Sub

Function UseArray(ByRef arrs() As String)
Dim name As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(arrs) To UBound(arrs)

    If Cells(3, i + 4) <> "" Then
        name = Cells(3, i + 4)

        Select Case name

            Case "Jeff"
                Call InfoPuller(arrs, 0)

            Case "Jonathan"
                Call InfoPuller(arrs, 1)

            Case "Jim"
                Call InfoPuller(arrs, 2)

            Case "Topher"
                Call InfoPuller(arrs, 3)

            Case "Brandon"
                Call InfoPuller(arrs, 4)

        End Select

    End If

Next i

End Function

Sub InfoPuller(ByRef link() As String, i As Integer)

Dim Pay1 As String, Pay2 As String, PayPeriod As String
Dim wkb As Workbook

Pay1 = Format(Cells(3, 2), "m-dd")
Pay2 = Format(Cells(24, 1), "m-dd")
PayPeriod = "" & Pay1 & " -- " & Pay2 & ""

'Jeff   (x,4) i = 0
'Jon    (x,5) i = 1
'Jim    (x,6) i = 2
'Topher (x,7) i = 3
'Brandon   (x,8) i = 4

Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(link(i))
' Pay period 1 Fill in

For j = 5 To 11
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PayPeriod).Cells(j, i + 4) = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(j + 4, 9).Value
Next j

' Mileage / Bridge Week 1

Dim Mileage As Integer, Bridge As Integer, Store As Integer, Store2 As Integer
Dim MandB As String


Mileage = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(28, 3).Value
Bridge = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(29, 3).Value
MandB = Mileage & " / " & Bridge

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PayPeriod).Cells(13, i + 4) = MandB

Store = Mileage
Store2 = Bridge

'Pay Period 2 Fill in
For j = 18 To 24
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PayPeriod).Cells(j, i + 4) = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(j + 1, 9).Value
Next j

' Mileage / Bridge Week 2

Mileage = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(28, 4).Value
Bridge = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(29, 4).Value
MandB = Mileage & " / " & Bridge

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PayPeriod).Cells(26, i + 4) = MandB

Store = Store + Mileage
Store2 = Store2 + Bridge

MandB = Store & " / " & Store2

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PayPeriod).Cells(31, i + 4) = MandB

wkb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

The problem is on this snippet.

```
For j = 5 To 11
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PayPeriod).Cells(j, i + 4) = Workbooks.Open(link(i)).Worksheets(PayPeriod).Cells(j + 4, 9).Value
 Next j
```

ThisWorkbook refers to the MasterSheet that the macro is running off of. PayPeriod is determined by the dates. Workbooks.Open(link(i)... is because if I try Workbooks(link(i)), it didn't like it (but it only opens up 1 copy, so I'm not worried about repeats).

As soon as it executes the Thisworkbook.sheets(PayPeriod), I hit the RTE-9 Subscript Out of Range error. The cells lines up, my pull data is right. I shortened the https link to just Sharepoint for privacy.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I will ask it while I digest the rest of the code, where do you close the workbooks you are opening?  Trying to open a workbook that is already open is going to cause you problems.  (I just don't yet know whether that is causing the problem you are experiencing.)

Comment: (a) I suggest doing a global find/replace of `Workbooks.Open(link(i)).` to `wbk.` to get around the issue I mentioned in my previous comment.  (b) What is the value of `PayPeriod` when it crashes?  The unqualified `Cells` in `Pay1 = Format(Cells(3, 2), "m-dd")` and `Pay2 = Format(Cells(24, 1), "m-dd")` mean that you are referring to the active sheet in the active workbook, so there is a possibility that's not the worksheet that contains your info.